# What's the best way to insert over a hundred million rows into a SQLite database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a load of data in CSV format.  I need to be able to index this data based on a single text field (the primary key), so I'm thinking of entering it into a database.  I'm familiar with sqlite from previous projects, so I've decided to use that engine.

After some experimentation, I realized that that storing a hundred million records in one table won't work well: the indexing step slows to a crawl pretty quickly.  I could come up with two solutions to this problem:

1. partition the data into several tables
2. partition the data into several databases

I went with the second solution (it yields several large files instead of one huge file).  My partition method is to look at the first two characters of the primary key: each partition has approximately 2 million records, and there are approximately 50 partitions.

I'm doing this in Python with the sqlite3 module.  I keep 50 open database connections and open cursors for the entire duration of the process.  For each row, I look at the first two characters of the primary key, fetch the right cursor via dictionary lookup, and perform a single insert statement (via calling execute on the cursor).

Unfortunately, the insert speed still decreases to an unbearable level after a while (approx. 10 million total processed records).  What can I do to get around this?  Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Do you need to update the data or just search? Is the key variable size (with big variations)? Is the content variable sized (big variations)?

Comment: I just need to search.  The data will be read-only.  The key and content is variable sized, but the variance isn't great.  The content is variable sized, with significant variance.

Comment: Check out this answer, it worked very well for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174355/laravel-insert-millions-of-database-rows-from-models/48176164#48176164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you have is that once the processing cannot just use in-memory buffers your hard disk head is just jumping randomly between 50 locations and this is dog slow.

Something you can try is just processing one subset at a time:

```
seen = {}   # Key prefixes already processed
while True:
    k0 = None  # Current prefix
    for L in all_the_data:
        k = L[0][:2]
        if k not in seen:
            if k0 is None:
                k0 = k
            if k0 == k:
                store_into_database(L)
    if k0 is None:
        break
    seen.append(k0)
```

This will do `n+1` passes over the data (where `n` is the number of prefixes) but will only access two disk locations (one for reading and one for writing). It should work even better if you've separate physical devices.

PS: Are you really really sure an SQL database is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Thanks!  The one-at-a-time thing is a good idea.  I'll give it a try.  Regarding your last question: no, I'm not sure that this is the best way.  I can't think of any other alternatives though...  can you?

Comment: Quite a few years ago (the PC was a 286) I've built a database of unique chess positions starting with 2 millions games (with an average of 70 positions per game). After banging my head against a wall for a while with standard databases the solution I found was based on a custom built file format and starting with a sort of the input data (trying to build the indexed data structure directly from random input was just making the hard disk scream).

Comment: I ended up doing it this way.  It will take a couple of hours (less than 48), but this is a one-off, so I can wait.

Answer (score 5):

- Wrap all insert commands into a single transaction.
- Use prepared statements.
- Create the index only after inserting all the data (i.e., don't declare a primary key).